# Redis too slow in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, redis

Using connect-redis on nodejs too slow. When i connect connect-redis to application performance drops

```
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
...
app1.use(session({
  store: new RedisStore(
    config.redisStore
  ),
  secret: 'asd',
  resave: false,
  rolling: true, 
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: config.redisStore.maxAge,
    httpOnly:false,
  },
}));
```

without this code in my app on apache bench i have about 3600 requests per second. With it code - about 2500. tested route in nodejs send only 'OK'

Why only creating "instance" of RedisStore leads to performance drops?

In app I do not use redisstore directly

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use ioredis npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioredis)

If you want to send a batch of commands (e.g. > 5), you can use pipelining to queue the commands in memory and then send them to Redis all at once. This way the performance improves by 50%~300%.